# UISearchBar in UINavigationItem.titleView not fully filled width

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

I have a UISearchBar in a titleView of Navigation bar, i did use [searchBar sizetofit] and create UISearchBar with frame of CGRectZero. But there is a small empty space on the left and right size of the UISearchBar inside titleView of Navigation.

[image: UISearchBar has empty on both side:]

```
theSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
theSearchBar.delegate = self;
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.theSearchBar;
[self.theSearchBar sizeToFit];

self.navigationItem.titleView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

//Change color of UISearchBar
theSearchBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102.0f/255.0f green:73.0f/255.0f     
blue:126.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

//Change color of NavigationBarItem
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102.0f/255.0f 
green:73.0f/255.0f blue:126.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

//Set background image for navigation bar
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:   
@"SearchBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I would like the UISearchBar fully fill the width of screen in both portrait and landscape..

Any help is really appreciated :)

Im using Xcode 4.5, iOS 6, with iPhone 5.

I only want to use navigationItem.titleView to host my UISearchBar, i think its better this way.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can hide the navigation bar, and add the **theSearchBar** to self.view
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:theSearchBar];

Comment: I tried this, but the searchBar didnt expand its size in landscape view. How do you get it to expand and retract back when user rotate? And how do you remove it from navigationBar on its child view?

Comment: I got it with autoresizingmask for thesearchbar :) and set it hidden on view disappear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just add these two lines in your code after setting the background image for navigation bar :

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil];
```

hope it works for you.